# Python: Alternative to hyperopt that can support multiprocessing?

Tags: python, mongodb, deep-learning, hyperparameters

Is there any other than `HyperOpt` that can support multiprocessing for a hyper-parameter search? I know that `HyperOpt` can be configured to use `MongoDB` but it seems like it is easy to get it wrong and spend a week in the weeds, is there anything that is more popular and effective?

Comment: Have you seen [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44181511/712995)?

Answer (score 2):

Check out Ray Tune!

You can use it for multiprocessing and multi-machine executions of random search, grid search, and evolutionary methods. It also has implementations of popular algorithms such as HyperBand.

Here's the docs page - [ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune.html](http://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune.html)

As an example to run 4 parallel experiments at a time:

```
import ray
import ray.tune as tune


def my_func(config, reporter):  # add the reporter parameter
    import time, numpy as np
    i = 0
    while True:
        reporter(timesteps_total=i, 
                 mean_accuracy=i ** config["alpha"])
        i += 1
        time.sleep(.01)


tune.register_trainable("my_func", my_func)
ray.init(num_cpus=4)
tune.run_experiments({
    "my_experiment": { 
        "run": "my_func", 
        "stop": { "mean_accuracy": 100 }, 
        "config": { 
            "alpha": tune.grid_search([0.2, 0.4, 0.6]), 
            "beta": tune.grid_search([1, 2]) } } })
```

Disclaimer: I work on this project - let me know if you have any feedback!

Comment: I believe ray isn't for windows, do you agree?

Comment: I tried running it for 1000 runs, I see overhead is more for the example that was given. Might be useful if you use *distributed training only*

Answer (score 1):

Some models(say RandomForest) have "njobs" parameter for use of number of cores. You can try njobs=-1; thus even if hyperopt uses 1 core, each trial would use all the cores, speeding up the process.