# Hyperparameter tuning locally -- Tensorflow Google Cloud ML Engine

Tags: tensorflow, gcloud, google-cloud-ml, tensorflow-estimator, hyperparameters

Is it possible to tune hyperparameters using ML Engine to train the model locally? The documentation only mentions training with hyperparameter tuning in the cloud (submitting a job), and has no mention to doing so locally.

Otherwise, is there another commonly used hyperparameter tuning that passes in command arguments to task.py as in the census estimator tutorial?

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/tree/master/census

Answer (score 2):

As Puneith said, hyperparamater tuning cannot run locally in ML-Engine.

SciKit Optimize provides an easy to use wrapper that works with any model including estimators. Just put the code that runs training for N epochs into its own function, which returns the evaluation 1-accuracy, 1-auroc or loss metric for minimizing.

```
import numpy as np
from skopt import gp_minimize

def train(hyperparam_config):
    # set from passed in hyperparameters
    learning_rate = hyperparam_config[0]
    num_layers = hyperparam_config[2]
    # run training
    res = estimator.train_and_evaluate()...
    return res['loss']  # return metric to minimize

hyperparam_config = [Real(0.0001, 0.01, name="learning_rate"),
                      Integer(3, 10, name="num_layers")]
res = gp_minimize(train, hyperparam_config)
with open('results.txt', 'w') as wf:
    wf.write(str(res))
print(res)
```

Source:
https://github.com/scikit-optimize/scikit-optimize/blob/master/examples/hyperparameter-optimization.ipynb

Answer (score 1):

You cannot perform HPTuning ([Bayesian Optimization](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/gcp/hyperparameter-tuning-cloud-machine-learning-engine-using-bayesian-optimization) based HPTuning which Cloud ML Engine supports) locally, since it's a managed service which Cloud ML Engine offers. There are other ways to perform Hyperparameter tuning e.g., Scikit-learn GridSearch but they are far less effective in this task.

Answer (score 0):

Check [Sherpa](https://github.com/LarsHH/sherpa), excellent Hyperparameter optimization library.

It says:

> Hyperparameter optimization that enables researchers to experiment, visualize, and scale quickly

There are many HyperParameter optimization libraries out there, but using Sherpa one can visualize the results.